# How to check if specific folders exist in a path in C#

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have a path for example C:/desktop and i wanna know if in this path are any folders named like folder A, folder B... i dont care whats in them i just need to know if they exist. ive seen the similar questions being asked but they were about splitting the path name, but the only path name i have is the most basic one, in those other question the path name was like, c:/desktop/folderA/folderB i wanna just know if C:/desktop/folderA exists or not and do it with a bunch of other folder names

Comment: there's a [`Directory.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=net-5.0) method you can use. Can you show an example of what you currently have as input and some pseudo code of how you intented to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `GetDirectories()`?

```
var folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:/desktop");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"location")){
//found it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an overload on the `GetDirectories` mentioned by @mxmissile to make it explicit you want to search to top directories only.

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:/desktop", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search through a folder with `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories`

In your case you should find your "Folder A" with:
`Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\desktop\", "folderA");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if `Directory.Exists()`. If you already know which folders you're looking for, you could do this:

```
var main_dir = @"C:\desktop\";
string[] folders = {"FolderA", "FolderB"};

string[] dir = new string[folders.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < folders.Length; ++i)
{
    dir[i] = Path.Combine(main_dir, folders[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(dir[i]);

    Console.WriteLine(Directory.Exists(dir[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you ask for. I have added a foreach to get all cases (folder A, b, c ...)

```
    bool directoryExist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"c:\desktop\forder A");
    foreach (var folderPath in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\desktop"))
    {
        string folderName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath);
        if (folderName == "Folder A") { //Case Sensible
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *querying* with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // Do we have in root
  string root = @"C:/desktop";

  // Any subdir(s) mentioned
  HashSet<string> subdirs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    @"folder A", 
    @"folder B",
  };

  bool contains = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Any(dir => subdirs.Contains(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name));
```

Change `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` into `SearchOption.AllDirectories` if you want *deep search* (if `root` itself or its any subdirectory has a folder mentioned in `subdirs`). You can alter the query to asnwer different questions:

```
  // If all subdirs exist:
  bool conatinsAll = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .All(dir => subdirs.Contains(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name)); 

  // Names of subdirs exist
  string[] existingSubDirs = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(dir => subdirs.Contains(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name))
    .ToArray();
```